# How are n-ary trees implemented when you don't know how many children a parent might have?

Tags: c, tree, filesystems

This is something I've been struggling with theoretically, but haven't found any good answers online. I've written programs with binary trees before, which were easy: each node had two links. But now I'm planning out a filesystem based on trees for a project, and I'm not sure how to proceed. Here's the trouble:

I want a tree that has pointers to files for leaves and subdirectories for internal nodes (I think this is how Unix does it?). But if a user wants to create a new file or directory, then the number of links in the parent node must be increased.

How can I account for this when I design my struct? I'm not sure what my options are besides hardcoding, say, 10 links and restricting directory members to that. Any pointers? (Hah, get it?)

If not, does anybody know of any good resources where I could learn more about this? Like I said, so far my internet searches have been fruitless.

Comment: UNIX typically does it by making a directory a file of arbitrary length, the contents of which are the names/inode numbers of each child file/directory

Comment: If you _really_ want to design a file system based on trees, do it like btrfs, where everything is just stored in one large b+tree. Non-trivial to grock, but extremely elegant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use a linked list of children.

Pardon my ASCII graphics:

```
+------+
|parent|
+------+
   |
   |
   \    +-----------+     +----------+       +----------+
    --->|first child|---->|next child|--...->|last child|-->NULL
        +-----------+     +----------+       +----------+
```

This makes it slighly tricker to walk the children, since to get the *n*:th child you need to visit the *n*-1 preceding children, but I think it's a viable approach that is used.

Comment: This is probably the most sensible method, though it will give you search issues, as suggested. +1 for taking the trouble to write ascii graphics.

Comment: This is a good idea. The reason I thought of the tree was because of the quick search and insertion times, but that might not be significant after all. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a linked list of children. e.g.:

```
struct tree {
   /* data */
   struct children_list* children;
}

struct children_list {
   struct tree* child;
   struct children_list* next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how Linux handles the directories 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode_pointer_structure

Answer (score 1):

make a node with data members=> 1.data 2.leftchild 3.rightsibling

suppose a parent has k children.
1st child will be pointed at by leftchild pointer in parent node..
2nd child will be pointed at by rightsibling pointer in 1st child..
In similar fashion ith child(1

This allows us navigation from parent to children & vice versa..
NOTE: Dummy node is just an indicator for last child...

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is have a list in each tree-node.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dynamically allocated array, and store the array pointer and its size. When you need to edit it, you just realloc it.

But, in this kind of situation, you should search for accepted solutions in OS and file system books, articles, scientific magazines/publications, etc.